# When trying to mount my UUID can't be found, how can I find

Tags: linux, mount, uuid

I'm building a lighting node, and run the command [sudo mount -a] I get this error saying my UUID I can't be found.

Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: There is no necessary post images. It's better to put commands in code block instead.

Answer (score 1):

You've formatted the filesystem with the command:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

and the output of the command above shows the new UUID. ( starting with b4cba65a - ....).

Comment: Yes I've done that but when I run [sudo mount -a] it keeps saying it can find it

Comment: update the new UUID in /etc/fstab and check if there is a line containing the old one. that's what says the output error.

Comment: I ran /etc/fstab i got a new UUID, and ran the same command checked fstab and placed the new UUID and got this message.

Comment: 'proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=342adec0-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=342adec0-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
UUID=1ce33383-7e3a-46ca-9d0e-a1d19d680d25 /mnt/hdd ext4 noexec,defaults 0 0'

Comment: did you format the / partition?  run `df -h`  and post the output

Answer (score 1):

The UUID (if it exists) can be found using the `blkid` command:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sdd1: UUID="58084476-829a-42c3-b823-4f1d42641fd4" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="ef9f27c6-4027-4620-9950-6a871b331fe9"
```